# Inlog page, redirects but doesn't read the code

Tags: php, html

I've made/copied a fitting and nice inlog page.
I've made it fully functional except there is one mistake, when the username and password arent in the DB it still redirects?
The login form:

```
  <div class="login">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="connectivity.php">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"  required/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required/>
            <input id="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="submit" value="Log-In">
        </br>
```

And the php code where its getting posted:

```
   <?php
session_start();
$user = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;


define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'mkuiper1');
define('DB_USER','mkuiper1');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password');


    $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    /*
    $ID = $_POST['user'];
    $Password = $_POST['pass'];
    */

    function SignIn($data){

        //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
        if(!empty($data['user'])){

            //$query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM WebsiteUsers where userName = '".$data['user']."' AND pass = '".$data['pass']."'") or die(mysql_error());
            // The above query is sql-injecation valnerable query, use the below query instead
            // Also do not use mysql erxtension anymore is deprecated, use mysqli instead
            // Let us say that your db connection is stored in $con variable

            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT *  FROM WebsiteUsers where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $data['user'],$data['pass']);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->store_result();
                if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
                        //echo "Login Succesvol!"; do not echo anything here before redirecting !!!
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else{
            $message = "Verkeerde Gebruikersnaam/Wachtwoord!";
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('$message')
            window.location = '/Sign-In.php';
            </SCRIPT>");
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        SignIn($_POST);
    }



    ?>
```

But it still goes and stays on connectivty.php, even when the pass and username are incorrect.

Sorry for the bad english

Jesse

Comment: please let me figure out your scenario, if the username is empty: go to sign in page, else if its not empty: try to find the username in the db, if found: create new session and redirect to index.php, right ?

Comment: Yes but it looks like when it doesnt find it, it will stay on the login-check page.

Comment: because your if statements are not well nested, also you are checking if the username is empty as the successor of condition, it should be `if(!empty(...))`, i'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, there are many issues with your code, this function should solve them:

```
function SignIn($data){

    //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
    if(!empty($data['user'])){

        //$query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM WebsiteUsers where userName = '".$data['user']."' AND pass = '".$data['pass']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        // The above query is sql-injecation valnerable query, use the below query instead
        // Also do not use mysql erxtension anymore is deprecated, use mysqli instead
        // Let us say that your db connection is stored in $con variable

        $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT *  FROM WebsiteUsers where userName = ? AND pass = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $data['user'],$data['pass']);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->store_result();
            if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
                    //echo "Login Succesvol!"; do not echo anything here before redirecting !!!
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            }
        }
    } else{
        $message = "Verkeerde Gebruikersnaam/Wachtwoord!";
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('$message')
        window.location = '/Sign-In.php';
        </SCRIPT>");
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    SignIn($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time! We are getting those 2 errors codes.

Notice: Undefined variable: con in 
connectivity.php on line 30

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in connectivity.php on line 30

This is weird because we already defined $con ...?

This is line 30: $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT *  FROM WebsiteUsers where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'");

Comment: @JesseVanDopperen of course you will get these errors, because `$con` is not declared in your code, have read the comments ?! you need to declare `$con` and assign a db connection to it.

Comment: We declared con, sorry I didnt mention it.

Comment: @JesseVanDopperen could you please share your code now

Comment: @Mohammed I editted my first post, now you can see the full code, also here at: http://pastebin.com/4wESrDqT